# Trigger para preencher tabela com dados de outra tabela

Tags: mysql, sql, trigger

Quero preencher uma tabela com os dados que forem sendo colocados em outra.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_jogo`AFTER INSERT 
ON `tabela1`
AS 
INSERT INTO `tabela2` SELECT * FROM `tabela1`;
```

Não consigo fazer o processo para copiar os dados da `tabela1` para a `tabela2`, assim sempre que um usuário se cadastrar, seus dados apareceram em duas tabelas.

Comment: Qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: MySQL? Oracle Database? PostgreSQL? MSSQL?

Comment: Estou utilizando MySQL como BD

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa pegar apenas o que foi inserido de novo, usando `NEW` como alias.

Por exemplo, imagina que "tabela1" seja assim e inseriu o registro 1:

| ID | DESCRICAO |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Teste |

Então use `NEW.ID` e `NEW.DESCRICAO`, por exemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_jogo`AFTER INSERT 
ON `tabela1`
AS 
INSERT INTO `tabela2`(ID, DESCRICAO) VALUES NEW.ID, NEW.DESCRICAO;
```

Do jeito que está fazendo vai inserir pra cada registro novo tudo o que tem na tabela.

Lembrando que todos esses exemplo são para `MySQL`

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER trg_jogo AFTER INSERT
ON tabela1
AS
INSERT INTO tabela2 (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email) VALUES NEW.user_login, NEW.user_pass, NEW.user_nicename, NEW.user_email;           Ele retornou um erro de sintaxe  "#1064-Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'AS
INSERT INTO tbl_curso_jogo (user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email' na linha 3 " a tabela2 é uma copia da tabela1 onde a primeira coluna é PK

Answer (score -1):

//using SQL Server

CREATE TRIGGER Yout_trigger_Name

ON Table1

FOR INSERT

AS

declare @id int

select @id = Id from Table2
BEGIN
INSERT Table2
Param1, Param2, Param3.....

FROM Table1

where id = @id + 1
END

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).